# Fill a DataTable with ReliableSqlConnection

Tags: c#, gridview, ado.net, datatable

I'm trying use the **ReliableSqlConnection** class (from the Transient Fault Handling Application Block NuGet package).

My end result is that I want to populate a GridView using the reliable retry mechanism.

My code looks like this:

```
        RetryStrategy retryStrategy = new Incremental("incremental", 5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

        IList<RetryStrategy> strategies = new List<RetryStrategy> { retryStrategy };
        RetryManager manager = new RetryManager(strategies, "incremental");
        RetryManager.SetDefault(manager);

        using (ReliableSqlConnection connection = 
                new ReliableSqlConnection(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorksLTConnectionString"].ConnectionString,
                    retryPolicy))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT top 5 [FirstName], [LastName], [CompanyName], [EmailAddress] FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]",
                    connection.Current);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            adapter.Fill(table);

            GridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Does the **Fill** method here use the **ExecuteReaderWithRetry** method internally?  Does it need to?  Or is it set up automatically to retry just by using the **ReliableSqlConnection** as my connection?

It's not entirely clear from the documentation exactly how this all works under the covers.

Comment: Good question, I looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156164.aspx and could not find it either.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will work? Have not tested it yet.

```
retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
});
```

found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268005/stored-procedure-populate-deleted-table-entities-back-to-dataset

**edit** a snippet of my code:

```
retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConStr()))
    {
        com.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        con.OpenWithRetry();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
});
```

I needed this for Azure SQL

Comment: If we only wrap the "da.Fill(dt)" in the ExecuteAction, would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work? Have not tested it yet.

```
DataTable GetTable(string commandText)
{
    DataTable DataTable = null;
    DataTable TempDataTable = null;
    try
    {
        TempDataTable = new DataTable();
        TempDataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        using (ReliableSqlConnection ReliableSqlConnection = new ReliableSqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            ReliableSqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, ReliableSqlConnection.Current))
            {
                SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                TempDataTable.Load(SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderWithRetry());
            }
        }
        DataTable = TempDataTable;
        TempDataTable = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (TempDataTable != null)
        {
            TempDataTable.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return DataTable;
}
```